# TCP Server Program System.OutOfMemoryException Issue

Tags: tcp, tcpserver

I have two Programs Client and Server using TCP and C#. Both are windows Service. Two-way communication. Client and Server both send and receive messages. I got System.OutOfMemoryException in Server Program when Send a message to Client after some Interval time(5 days once based on Load).I have attached some images. Have a look. [in this link mentioned which line I got exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpyrB.png)Please help me to sort out this issue.

[State Object Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVJSI.png)

Comment: and what's the exception message?

Comment: Message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
STACK TRACE :   at TowaServer.CommonHelper.GetBuffer()
   at TowaServer.TowaSocketListener.SendForAll()